# Selenium IDE via command line without the below error

Tags: selenium

I am trying to run Selenium IDE testsuite.html in the following way

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar -htmlSuite "*firefox" "http://myserverhere" "C:\SELENIUM_STANDALONE\MAT.html" "C:\SELENIUM_STANDALONE\results.html"
```

But it throws the below error:

> It looks like your baseUrl (http://myserverhere) is pointing to a
>   file, not a directory (it doesn't end wi th a /).  We're going to have
>   to strip off the last part of the pathname.
>   jar:file:/C:/SELENIUM_STANDALONE/selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar!/customPr
>   ofileDirCUSTFFCHROME

Comment: Have you tried adding a trailing `/` as hinted at in the error?

Comment: also it is not working correctly , just tww firefox window opens and there are some control pannel there but even if i manually press paly it will not work please help